# Set status button, wanting to set status back to default

Tags: php

I wonder if you could help me:

I have 5 buttons at the top of my database website so an engineer can click on it to change the status of the current job, now, could someone help me please, I want it to work both ways = Click button to set status and if the job comes back then click on the same button to UNSET status.

```
<div class="col-sm-2" onclick="mark_in_workshop(<?php echo $Return->return_id ?>)">
<span class="fa <?php if ($Return->date_into_workshop > 0) { echo "glyphicon-green"; } else { echo "glyphicon-grey"; } ?> fa-cogs"></span>
<h4>In Workshop</h3>
<h5><?php if ($Return->date_into_workshop > 0) { echo date("d M, Y", $Return->date_into_workshop); } ?></h5>
</div>
```

So that code would be default glyphicon-grey, the engineer clicks on it to make it glyphicon-green to set it into workshop. Now I want to be able to click the same button again to set the status back to glyphicon-grey if the job returns to the workshop.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: pass the true/false as a `parameter` in your function and then `return !parameter` when clicking the button. That will make it alternate between the true/false state.

Comment: you should update your question and show us the code submitting the update request and dealing with the response